# Is giving one side advantage always equivalent to giving disadvantage to the opponent?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, statistics, advantage-and-disadvantage

Sometimes, players get advantage; sometimes, monsters get disadvantage. Sometimes it's not clear whether to give someone advantage or his opponent disadvantage, especially in improvised contests (PHB 195).

I know enough about statistics to know that "roll two, take highest" can produce tricky results. Therefore, I ask:

**In a contest with otherwise constant bonuses, is giving one side advantage always equivalent to giving his opponent disadvantage?**

This could matter e.g. if a player maneuvers a monster into an unfortunate situation. Now it feels better for the player to gain advantage, when more logically the monster is at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all other things being equal, giving disadvantage to one side is mathematically equivalent to giving advantage to the other side.

[Anydice link](http://anydice.com/program/6d54).

Comment: I think this answer needs some additional detail. To anyone not already familiar with AnyDice, it isn't inherently clear what that page is illustrating. A verbal explanation of why the two situations are mathematically equivalent will improve this answer significantly.

Comment: Also this only applies in contested rolls not in combat. I know the question specifies but I think it's worth emphasising anyway lest anyone hastily generalise.

Comment: The binary nature of advantage is a HUGE exception to the plain arithmetic.  Passing over it makes this answer less useful than confusing.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question in a useful way unless you're familiar with AnyDice. Also it's just a link, which could go down. The information would be more useful if it were here.

Answer (score 51):

Possible exceptions:

- The player already has advantage; granting them advantage again does nothing, but imposing disadvantage on the monster does.
- The 'Lucky' feat allows the underdog with disadvantage to go from "roll two, choose the worst" to effectively "roll three, choose the best".
- Asymmetry: Stopping the bad guy from doing something might be more important than you doing something (particularly if the rest of the party can do it instead/as well)
- The odds of criticals shift immensely: it's nearly impossible to crit with disadvantage (1/400).
- Sometimes granting advantage/disadvantage triggers side-effects: e.g. Sneak Attack.
- In a multi-competitor contest, advantage might help against everyone, whereas disadvantaging your opponents might be on an opponent-by-opponent basis.

But most importantly:

- Disadvantage makes the monster suck. Advantage makes the character awesome. Go for awesome!

Comment: Also, they are only equivalent when there are exactly two factions and exactly two outcomes. Any situation with more complexity and nuance, then the advantage and disadvantage are not identical.

Comment: As I understand it, Lucky lets you reroll.  So with disadvantage, you roll two and take the worst *then* roll a third and take the better of that roll and the worst of the original pair.  Its not *quite* as good as best of 3, and probably not as good as best of 2, but it's certainly better than worst of 2.

Comment: In a contest, the odds of a critical hit with advantage are not important, because when the enemy has disadvantage his odds of a critical miss increase. Chance of success thus stays the same.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman [Lucky might be kind of broken](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68970/how-is-the-lucky-feat-affected-by-advantage-disadvantage)

Comment: One more thing: Imposing disadvantage on someone/thing automatically removes any advantage they had previously. And vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, that can't be the intended result of Lucky + Disadvantage.  Especially since Lucky says "You can choose to spend one of your luck points after you roll the die, but before the outcome is determined."  In the case of Disadvantage, 'the die' is the lower of 2d20.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman that's what I thought too, which is why I houserule it that way, but official sources still say otherwise

Comment: These are useful, but it just starts with "possible exceptions". Exceptions to what? Exceptions to Miniman's answer? I think I know what you probably mean, but it could use some clarification

Comment: Another difference is many players would prefer to be rolling more dice (to their advantage or disadvantage) for either tactile or perceived control reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I think the one big point that's been glazed over is it depends on the number of attacks (or rolls) on both sides.

If we're talking about two relatively equal "things" (ie two fighters of about same level), it's probably not going to make any different.

However, let's look at a more "extreme" side case to see what I'm getting at.

Let's assume you're fighter (with 2 attacks) is up against a creature with 4 attacks.

Giving disadvantage to the creature with 4 attacks will tend to have a bigger impact on the fight, than advantage to the fighter with less attacks.

In short, the more rolls (not just attacks - that's just a simple example in this case), the more influence.

Comment: lol. love the obligatory downvotes and no feedback ... :\  *sigh*

Comment: In this case it's probably that the answer can't stand alone.  It's not a good answer by itself; it's an edge case.  It's like if you asked "Is STR better than INT on a barbarian?" and someone answered "One thing everyone else forgot is that McGuffin X lets you add INT to damage with Greataxe attacks by left-handed characters."  Sure, it might technically be true, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @gatherer818: thanks, yeah, I post this kind of thing as a comment, and it gets comments "post that as an answer", so I post an answer, and get the opposite ;)  Can't win sometimes .. lol  It's why I stated it the way I did - already accepted answer - and I'm not contesting it .. just adding info/thoughts on exactly that, an "edge" case. *shrug* Cheers!

Comment: @Neuneck: where does it say "all other thigns being equal" ? I'm not seeing it? it mentions "constant bonuses" .. that's a big leap between those two .. and why I talked about multiple rolls (not a difference in bonuses)

Comment: @Ditto Whoops, indeed I didn't put it there explicitly, just other bonuses being constant (to not make the statistics any more compliated). Still I referred to contests, not attacks.