Why does a halfing's racial trait lucky specify you must use the next roll?
By definition, it can only be the same or better, unlike Great Weapon Fighting, where you could re-roll a 2 and get a 1.

If you think that's odd, you should see what happens when you combine Lucky with Disadvantage - https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68970/how-is-the-lucky-feat-affected-by-advantage-disadvantage

The most straightforward reason for this language is to clarify that you only re-roll once because of Lucky.
The full text of the Lucky feature is:

When you roll a 1 on the d20 for an attack roll, ability check, or saving throw, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll.

So if you roll a 1, the Halfling’s Lucky trait lets you re-roll that die. But if the re-rolled result is also a 1, you don’t get to re-roll it again; you have to use that result.
Another reason for this specific language to make a clear distinction between this re-roll - where you must take the second result - and advantage. Advantage is the more commonly-encountered “roll two dice” mechanic, so this wording also makes it clear you don’t get to choose the result you want from both rolls. Many re-roll abilities (for example the Fighter’s Indomitable class feature) use similar language, but have other triggers than a natural 1, meaning the second roll could be worse. So consistency is also a likely factor.
Like Lucky, most of these re-roll abilities are optional, so you can keep the initial result by choosing not to re-roll at all. But it’s true there are very few reasons anyone would ever want to do so in the case of Lucky.

I feel they chose an unnecessarily confusing/tangential wording for that purpose, but yeah, it is a concise way to describe that behavior. +1 from me.

@ShadowRanger I’ll add this in, but it’s also to make a re-roll clearly distinct from advantage, where you get a choice of which die to use.

This makes sense - it is there to prevent you from making multiple rerolls in the rare case you roll another 1.

Here is a highly contrived scenario: You attack a wotarie which unbeknownst to you has extremely low health. You roll a 1, decide to reroll, and your second roll is a natural 20, killing the beast unexpectedly, when you didn't really want that. You can't change your mind and decide to keep the original roll.

There are some extremely niche scenarios where it matters
Quoting an answer where this matters:

Second Case: Feat then Feature

Or if you use a luck point and that dice rolls a 1, do you reroll it with Halfling Luck and then still get to choose any?

Not quite. The roll is whichever you choose when you use in the feat Lucky. So, you could choose the 1, and then get to re-roll, as per RAW, but you'd have to use the number of that Halfling luck reroll not the previous two.

Basically, if you:

Roll a d20 for a check and it comes up 5
Spend a Luck point from the Lucky feat to roll an extra die, and that die comes up 1
Thinking the 5 won't be good enough, you decide to choose the Lucky feat die as your result, and hope the reroll is better than 5
The reroll actually comes up less than 5, and now you're stuck with that result (because you "must use the new roll"), even if the original roll of 5 might have succeeded

This differs from advantage (where you're officially required to use the higher roll, unlike with a Lucky granted die), where this won't matter.

The wording in Lucky doesn't affect this interaction. When you at step 3 choose the Lucky feat die as your result, the 5 doesn't exist any more. The fact that you later get to reroll the result doesn't magically make a previously discarded die result available.

@JoakimM.H. I agree with that, but it's potentially clearer and more obvious to more players reading that rule if they phrase it this way.  (They might come to the right conclusion for the wrong reason about this feat / feature interaction, or it might prompt them to think at all about which die results they're allowed to choose from.)  So the phrasing isn't necessary for this reason, but is still maybe helpful in that case.

The wording is likely inherited from older similar rules.
While it's odd to specify "you must use the new roll" when it can't be worse than the old roll, it makes more sense in the context that this wording was used in other works, where a reroll is made in circumstances other than natural 1, such that the second roll can be worse.
For example, in the D&D 4e sourcebook Mordenkainen's Magnificent Emporium, which notably had 5e's lead designer Jeremy Crawford as its lead developer, there are various magic items which allow a reroll on some circumstance:

Once before the end of the encounter, you can reroll a failed skill check, attack roll, or saving throw. You must use the second result.


When you fail a monster knowledge check related to a ceature with this origin and type, you can reroll the check by spending one hour studying the bestiary. You must use the second result.


Once before the end of your next turn, when you miss with a divine attack power, you can reroll the attack roll. You must use the second result.

This language previously appears in D&D 3.5 too. Magic Item Compendium p.69:

You must activate this ability before the success or failure of the saving throw has been determined, and you must use the second result, even if it's lower.

The idea, it seems, is to clarify how rerolling generally works. The reroll replaces the original roll. You don't pick the better of the two, you essentially discard your first result to make it again, because that's just how rerolling works. There's almost never a downside to rerolling a natural 1, but you still have to take the new one because that's just what reroll means.

The primary reason is just to communicate that if the second roll is also a nat1, it doesn't apply again.
So a nat 1 is still possible, just 20 times less likely.
Other phrasings would be possible for that, but this is the one they chose; it's similar to other reroll abilities even though the situation is different.

If succeeding by too much (like a nat20) would also be bad, it doesn't give you the option of keeping the 1 in a situation where you think a nat20 would be even worse.
I've heard of some DMs interpreting a nat20 in ways that are actually detrimental to the character, like "you succeed so hard at lifting him that you actually throw him over the wall", or if you were trying to break a lock, maybe you smash the whole box.  i.e. that a nat20 on a strength check means more strength, rather than the perfect amount of strength applied correctly to achieve the intended outcome.
If you're playing with a DM like that, there are times when failure might be better than a nat20.  (Although I'd guess most such DMs would also have ridiculous penalties for crit fails because they find stuff like that funny in general.)
I don't know if this was something the rules designers considered when choosing that wording; probably not since I've seen actual-play streams of games run by Jeremy Crawford, Chris Perkins, and Mike Mearls, and I don't remember them ever penalizing a player for a nat 20.  But as written, this is one corner-case effect that hasn't been mentioned yet.
With a DM who treats a nat 20 as being as successful as possible rather than as strong as possible, it's harder to come up with a use case for keeping the nat 1.  Perhaps you really want to avoid revealing your full capabilities, and you'd rather suffer a minor inconvenience like falling into a stream while trying to scamper over some low rock than put on a dazzling show of acrobatics with a nice save.  (That still depends on DM interpretation of a nat 20, like that nat 20 lets you make it look easy and not showy, or that a deception check would be a separate roll.)
